# What is the alternative for AmazonDynamoDBClient that got deprecated?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone know what has replaced AmazonDynamoDBClient? 
Couldn't find anything in the documentation

Package - com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2

```
    AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the [API doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html), the builder class (e.g. `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder`) should be used to create the instance.

**Sample code using the builder class:-**

I have create the client for DynamoDB local.

```ava
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-east-1")).build());

Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Movies");
```

**Scan using DynamoDB table class:-**

```ava
private static void findProductsForPriceLessThanZero() {

        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);

        Map<String, Object> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        expressionAttributeValues.put(":pr", 100);

        ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> items = table.scan(
            "Price < :pr", //FilterExpression
            "Id, Title, ProductCategory, Price", //ProjectionExpression
            null, //ExpressionAttributeNames - not used in this example 
            expressionAttributeValues);

        System.out.println("Scan of " + tableName + " for items with a price less than 100.");
        Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next().toJSONPretty());
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Refer this link for Dynamodb endpoints  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region ... If you are not using the local DynamoDB, the endpoint may not be required as it will be derived automatically based on region. Alternatively, you can use the endpoints as given in the above link.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering if this can help me get all records in a table at one go?

Comment: Yes, you can scan the table recursively to get all the items in the table. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html

Comment: I am able to do that using - ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(tableName);
        ScanResult result = amazonDynamoDBClient.scan(scanRequest); //And then use result.getItems()

Comment: Yes, but the scan method is available in AmazonDynamoDBClient - and the answer above use DynamoDB

Comment: Here's a related question that I posted on getting 403 forbidden when I post a request to elastic search. This is how I am using ScanRequest class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932026/why-do-i-get-403-forbidden-error-while-posting-a-json-to-elasticsearch-endpoint

Comment: Refer this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html#DocumentAPIJavaScanExample .. updated the same in awswer for reference ..

Answer (score 2):

I am using spring-boot, the way I am working with Dynamo is injecting an AWSCredentialsProvider and using the variables which are in my environment in this way:

```js
@Bean
public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
    AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB
            = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider).build();
    return amazonDynamoDB;
}

@Bean
public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
    return new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider();
}
```

The full example is available here: https://github.com/ioet/bpm-skills-api